# It's correct to call "deployment" to the group of pieces to be manufactured?

Tags: word-usage

I have a product definition (furniture) that has all the subcomponents explained based on the relation with his parent product. With formulas.

The structure of this description is called "**Configuration**".

When I sell a unit of the defined product, I create, "deployment?" of the components, in which each formula, from Configuration, is executed and only his result is stored.

The resulting information of this process is, all data for for manufacturing. Because of this I think that this is a "**Deployment of the Configuration**".

I know that I can call it Composition, but this word is more near to the Configuration meaning that to the Deployment meaning. I think. And I've used Composition in other context. When I execute the formulas but not for manufacturing, instead for budgets.

Comment: It's for a manufacturing desktop application.

Comment: Since you mention the word "sell"... Are you looking for language that would describe a royalty charged to the end-user each time he uses a generated configuration to control a manufacturing process?

Comment: .... or to control a manufacturing "run"?

Comment: No.
I don't want to describe a royalty charge. And, yes. I want describe a manufacturing process.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Deploy X* means "to send X to a wide area or many number of places/recipients."  It's also used when there is only a single recipient or destination, if the method used to send would also be the same as one used for many recipients or destinations.

Typical things that are *deployed* are vehicles, systems, and configurations of systems - the last meaning very prevalent in IT.

So you can say you've deployed a configuration to the manufacturing system.

The item being manufactured in your scenario is *not* something that is deployed, though.